# Not able to randomize two numbers to be different and not present in an array

Tags: java, arrays, math, random

My current code is:

```
     int[] usedRVals = new int[8];
     int[] usedCVals = new int[8];
     Arrays.fill(usedRVals, 99);
     Arrays.fill(usedCVals, 99);



        for (int l = 0; l < 8; l++) {
        r = 0;
        c = 0;
        // get new random numbers that aren't the same
        while (r == c && !Arrays.asList(usedRVals).contains(r) && !Arrays.asList(usedCVals).contains(c)) {
            r = randomNum();
            c = randomNum();
        }
        usedRVals[l] = r;
        usedCVals[l] = c;
   }


 private static int randomNum() {

        Random r = new Random();
        return r.nextInt(8);

    }
```

I'm attemping to get a new number (between 0 and 7) that hasn't been used before in the same loop, but I'm unable to find the logic error in my code. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: First of all, your logic is off. You should be looping while it *is* in the list. Second of all, you can't use `Arrays.asList()` for primitive arrays.

Comment: You should not be creating a `new Random()` repeatedly. (It's a poorly-named class.) It really is a RandomNumberGenerator, and each time you create it, you reset it to the beginning. It should be assigned as a static or when everything begins, and you should seed it with something that has a bit of randomness to it, or variability to it, if possible (such as the current time). Then each time you ask the same `Random` for the next value, it will give you something different, instead of the same number each time.

Comment: @ErikE You shouldn't seed it unless you specifically need reproducible results. The [default seed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random--) will generally prevent repeated sequences. But it's true that you should use a single `Random` instance for a sequence.

Comment: Thank you, I knew there was a logic error I wasn't seeing. Where could I learn about better ways to make a random method? I can't seem to find any. And is there a good alternative to Arrays.asList() for my array?

Comment: The better alternative to using `Arrays.asList()` on your array is to just use a `List` instead of an array in the first place.

Comment: @shmosel ok thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: My advice is construct a random permutation of 0, 1, 2, ... 7 and then emit those values two by two; that will ensure there are no duplicates. A web search for "Knuth shuffle" or "random permutation" should find some resources.